# Generate DAX Table that responds to user filter selections

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table (Table1) with data about Products that are sold on particular dates along with the product Class at the time of sale.  Here is a sample for testing and understanding:

| Product | Date | Qty | Class |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| D | 14/08/2023 | 78 | X |
| C | 14/08/2023 | 41 | Y |
| E | 14/08/2023 | 56 | X |
| C | 14/08/2023 | 27 | X |
| E | 14/08/2023 | 6 | Z |
| D | 14/08/2023 | 62 | X |
| C | 14/08/2023 | 50 | Y |
| C | 14/08/2023 | 15 | Y |
| D | 14/08/2023 | 57 | Y |
| E | 14/08/2023 | 44 | Y |
| D | 15/08/2023 | 38 | X |
| E | 15/08/2023 | 23 | W |
| D | 15/08/2023 | 67 | X |
| B | 15/08/2023 | 14 | Z |
| C | 15/08/2023 | 15 | W |
| B | 15/08/2023 | 49 | X |
| C | 15/08/2023 | 1 | Z |
| E | 15/08/2023 | 23 | Z |
| E | 15/08/2023 | 67 | Y |
| B | 15/08/2023 | 76 | X |
| E | 22/08/2023 | 66 | Y |
| C | 22/08/2023 | 70 | X |
| E | 22/08/2023 | 79 | Y |
| E | 22/08/2023 | 65 | X |
| D | 22/08/2023 | 79 | Y |
| E | 22/08/2023 | 30 | X |
| B | 22/08/2023 | 9 | Y |
| B | 22/08/2023 | 54 | Y |
| B | 22/08/2023 | 32 | Y |
| D | 22/08/2023 | 78 | Y |
| B | 23/08/2023 | 41 | Y |
| D | 23/08/2023 | 62 | Y |
| D | 23/08/2023 | 62 | X |
| B | 23/08/2023 | 58 | X |
| E | 23/08/2023 | 10 | W |
| B | 23/08/2023 | 57 | X |
| C | 23/08/2023 | 42 | Y |
| B | 23/08/2023 | 27 | Y |
| D | 23/08/2023 | 25 | X |
| D | 23/08/2023 | 11 | X |

I want to create a DAX table that looks at each product that existed on the Last Day and shows the maximum Class for that day and then shows the Class for each Product on the First Day.  If the Product was not sold on the First Day, then the Class is marked as "New".

To do this, I defined two DAX measures:

```
MinSelectedDate = MIN( Table1[Date] )
```

and

```
MaxSelectedDate = MAX( Table1[Date] )
```

And I am using this DAX table:

```
LastDayProductClassWithNewDynamic = 
VAR MinDate = [MinSelectedDate]
VAR MaxDate = [MaxSelectedDate]
RETURN
    SUMMARIZE(
        FILTER(
            ALL(Table1),
            Table1[Date] = MaxDate || Table1[Date] = MinDate
        ),
        Table1[Product],
        "FirstDayClass", IF(ISBLANK(CALCULATE(MAX(Table1[Class]), Table1[Date] = MinDate)), "New", CALCULATE(MAX(Table1[Class]), Table1[Date] = MinDate)),
        "LastDayClass", CALCULATE(MAX(Table1[Class]), Table1[Date] = MaxDate)
    )
```

The result is correct for the **MinSelectedDate** of 14 August and the **MaxSelectedDate** of 23 August:

| **Product** | **FirstDayClass** | **LastDayClass** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | New | Y |
| C | Y | Y |
| D | Y | Y |
| E | Z | W |

When the user sets the Date Filter to have **MinSelectedDate** of 15 August and the **MaxSelectedDate** of 22 August, the measures calculate correctly.  However, the **LastDayProductClassWithNewDynamic** does not change.  It gives the same result as the table above.  It should give:

| **Product** | **FirstDayClass** | **LastDayClass** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | X | Y |
| C | W | X |
| D | X | Y |
| E | W | X |

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and what correction I should make?

Comment: Is your DAX table a calculated table? If so, it won't be recalculated when a user changes a slicer - it is computed once at refresh time.

Comment: Hi Davide - yes it is.

Comment: Well, that's your answer. Calculated tables don't respond to slicers.

Comment: Thanks Davide - I will have to go about this in a different way.  :-)